# data validation in google sheet with 2 columns

Tags: google-sheets

I Need help to apply data validation by referencing from another column with a specific value.
In the given link for google sheet, I have some data where I need to restrict entry of duplicate data only if value from ColumnA is repeated and in ColumnC value is 1 but if value in ColumnC is 0 and data in ColumnA is repeated it should allow it.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jIfIrB2RsCIyfk-64iyzNGz91oT82C56TDffVeFGLL0/edit?usp=sharing

Note: I have highlighted the rows which need to fixed using any solution. Solution should not allow data entry in row17 with value 1 in ColumnC as it's already available in row7 with value 1 in ColumnC.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a sheet in your file 'Aresvik solution', but an anonymous user keeps altering your file so I've created another file for you here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11y1cce5pNRh9KDifzZZg_VmsmWh2xrv4bBDDwM2awa8/copy

Using `query`, it filters out rows where `Col2>1 and Col3=1`:

```
=query({Sheet1!A:C},"where not (Col2>1 and Col3=1)",1)
```

[image]

Not sure what your intention is with `1230A`, value `1`? If you only want to ignore dupes where status = 1, then try:

```
=arrayformula(query({Sheet1!A:C,if(Sheet1!C:C=1,countifs(Sheet1!A:A&"-"&Sheet1!C:C,Sheet1!A:A&"-"&Sheet1!C:C),)},"select Col1,Col2,Col3 where Col4 is null or Col4=1",1))
```

[image]

If you want a warning when there is a duplicate status of 1, try this in cell `D1`:

```
=arrayformula({"Warning";if(if(Sheet1!C2:C=1,countifs(Sheet1!A2:A&"-"&Sheet1!C2:C,Sheet1!A2:A&"-"&Sheet1!C2:C),)>1,"Issue",)})
```

[image]

Comment: Purpose is to manage inventory transactions, I update status column with 1 or 0 manually. If I receive it status will be 0 and if I issue it status will be 1. suppose 1 particular asset(1230E) issued or received multiple times, transactions status will be 0 for all except one entry. It's not possible to issue same asset to multiple persons. Status column I update manually so it's possible that I make same asset entry with status 1 to avoid this problem I want some kind of validation/conditional formatting which restricts entry or give me warning

Comment: I've updated my solution, but it would help if you could list all possible examples in your source data where you wish to ignore the records (things like input errors), and then when there are remaining dupes, which of the dupes do you want to pick (first in the sheet [top] or last in the sheet [bottom]). Since it's an inventory system, would you also include a date/time stamp relative to each transaction?

Comment: I just need to highlight or restrict entry of duplicates where status is 1 for same entry in columnA so that if I make a duplicate entry with status 1 than I'll know that status for this particular entry is issued. Filtration of duplicate where status is 1 not needed, something like conditional formatting for highlight or data validation to restrict duplicate entry with status 1. In your last solution you filtered out duplicate but I need all data just want to highlight or restrict the duplicate with status 1

Comment: OK, so you can just create a 'Warning' column in cell `D1` as per the solution above: `=arrayformula({"Warning";if(if(Sheet1!C2:C=1,countifs(Sheet1!A2:A&"-"&Sheet1!C2:C,Sheet1!A2:A&"-"&Sheet1!C2:C),)>1,"Issue",)})`. Then a conditional formatting rule over cells `A1:C1000` with custom formula `=$D1="Issue"`. You can take a copy of sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11y1cce5pNRh9KDifzZZg_VmsmWh2xrv4bBDDwM2awa8/copy

Comment: Given your explanation, this solution works for me, @user3244104 can you confirm that? I'd like to respect this answer instead of formulating another.